# jQuery: Targeting element with prev()

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to add `class="required"` to a `label` element, which in it simplest form (input type="text", appears in the following structure from our forms software:

```
<div>
    <label>X</label>
</div>
<input required type="text">
```

Basically, the label is wrapped in a div, so the following works nicely:

```
var a = $('*[required]').prev();
var b = a.find('label');
if (b)
    b.addClass('required');
```

However, sometimes the gap between `<input>` and `<label>` is bigger, eg, when it's a radio button:

```
 <div>
    <label>X</label>
</div>
<span>
    <div>
        <input required type="radio">
    </div>
</span>
```

So, how can I target the label if it is a bit further back? I tried chaining `.prev()` but couldn't get this to work.

Comment: `prev()` targets the previous sibling, you have a parent/child structure that prevents this. If you want to use `prev()` then you have to target the prev() of the parent and find the child you are after.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be much easier if you used labels properly. Use the `for` attribute to tie it to an input based on ID (make sure the IDs on your inputs are all unique):

```
<div>
    <label for="foo">X</label>
</div>

<input id="foo" required type="text"/>

$('*[required]').each(function() {
    var l = $('label[for="' + this.id + '"]');
    if(l.length > 0) {
        l.addClass('required');
    }
    else {
        // some convoluted and easily broken DOM traversal fallback
    }
});
```

Comment: We do, just simplified the HTML above for pasting. Good idea, I did not think of that...ties it nicely to best practice too. +1 for thinking of accessibility